# WHERE clause in MDX for Dynamic Management Views

Tags: sql-server, mdx, ssas-tabular, dmv

I am trying to query the metadata from a tabular cube using DMVs.  I was able to get it to work without a where clause, but I can't seem to get a where clause to work.  Any Advice?

Here is the code that works:

```
SELECT 
    [MEASURE_CAPTION]           AS [Measure]
    ,[MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE]       AS [Visable]
    ,[DESCRIPTION]              AS [Description]
    ,[MEASURE_DISPLAY_FOLDER]   AS [Display Folder]
    ,[EXPRESSION]               AS [Calculation]
FROM $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

The WHERE clauses that I have tried are:

```
WHERE ([MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE].[members].[true])
```

I get the following error:

```
The dot expression is not allowed in the context at line 9, column 1.
```

Also:

```
WHERE [MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE] = TRUE
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: A Boolean expression is not allowed in the context at line 9, column 7.
```

I have tried many veriations on these themes, but always get the same result.  I am not at all familiar with how MDX works, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE` is a boolean column and must be filtered as such.  The following query filters the results to only those with a `MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE` value of true.  Change this to `WHERE NOT MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE` for rows where this is false.  You can see the datatypes for this DMV from the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee301649(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT 
    [MEASURE_CAPTION]           AS [Measure]
    ,[MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE]       AS [Visable]
    ,[DESCRIPTION]              AS [Description]
    ,[MEASURE_DISPLAY_FOLDER]   AS [Display Folder]
    ,[EXPRESSION]               AS [Calculation]
FROM $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES 
WHERE MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was what I needed.